# Using LINQ with a WHERE to ask for multiple possible results without redundant "||" commands

Tags: c#, linq

This is a cosmetics issue, it is syntactical sugar only, just because I want to do it. But basically I have a lot of code that reads like this ... I am using a `dynamic` for the sheer purpose of time saving and example.

```
var terms = new List<string> {"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "rho"};

var list = new List<dynamic> {
    new {
        Foo = new List<string> {
            "alpha",
            "gamma"
        }
    }
};

var result = list
     .Where(
          n => n.Foo.Contains(terms[0]) ||
               n.Foo.Contains(terms[1]) ||
               n.Foo.Contains(terms[2]) ||
               n.Foo.Contains(terms[3]) ||
               n.Foo.Contains(terms[4]) ||
               n.Foo.Contains(terms[5]))
     .ToList();
```

Obviously this is a ludicrous hyperbole for the sheer sake of example, more accurate code is ...

```
    Baseline =
        Math.Round(Mutations.Where(n => n.Format.Is("Numeric"))
            .Where(n => n.Sources.Contains("baseline") || n.Sources.Contains("items"))
            .Sum(n => n.Measurement), 3);
```

But the basic point is that I have plenty of places where I want to check to see if a `List<T>` (usually `List<string>`, but there may at times be other objects. `string` is my present focus though) contains any of the items from another `List<T>`.

I thought that using `.Any()` would work, but I actually haven't been able to get that to function as expected. So far, only excessive `"||"` is all that yields the correct results.

This is functionally fine, but it is annoying to write. I wanted to know if there is a simpler way to write this out - an extension method, or a `LINQ` method that perhaps I've not understood.

## Update

I am really aware that this **may** be a duplicate, but I am having a hard time figuring out the wording of the question to a level of accuracy that I can **find** duplicates. Any help is much appreciated.

## Solution

Thank you very much for all of the help. This is my completed solution. I am using a `dynamic` here just to save time on example classes, but several of your proposed solutions worked.

```
var terms = new List<string> {"alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "rho"};

var list = new List<dynamic> {
    new  { // should match
        Foo = new List<string> {
            "alpha",
            "gamma"
        },
        Index = 0
    },
    new { // should match
        Foo = new List<string> {
            "zeta",
            "beta"
        },
        Index = 1
    },
    new { // should not match
        Foo = new List<string> {
            "omega",
            "psi"
        },
        Index = 2
    },
    new  { // should match
        Foo = new List<string> {
            "kappa",
            "epsilon"
        },
        Index = 3
    },
    new  { // should not match
        Foo = new List<string> {
            "sigma"
        },
        Index = 4
    }
};

var results = list.Where(n => terms.Any(t => n.Foo.Contains(t))).ToList();

// expected output - [0][1][3]
results.ForEach(result => {
    Console.WriteLine(result.Index);
});
```

Comment: Probably something like `where Foo.Intersect(terms).Any()` would do it.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way like that, yeah. I've never had any experience with `Intersect`, and the documentation on it is pretty confusing. Have any examples of it in action?

Comment: Intersect is a standard term from set theory. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)

Comment: @Ciel, the property called Foo is exaclty the same as "alpha" or "beta" etc or Foo coould be something like "asdasdaalpha" and since this contains alpha string will be included?

Comment: Forgive me, I will update the example. `Foo`, in this example, is a `List<string>`, but it could be anything. I assume once I can make this work with strings, taking it a step further to real objects will not be much harder.

Comment: @Christos, I have updated the example. Forgive me, I was completely unclear and I see where what I presented was non-sensical.

Comment: @no problem dude. then my answer should work. Please test it and let me know. Thank you !

Comment: Wow, the outpouring of useful information in this thread is overwhelming. Is there a way I can award points to multiple people?

Comment: @Grant Winney, I spent a long time reading up all of the stuff you showed me and trying various examples and I am totally psyched about the kinds of things I can start doing with `IEqualityComparer<T>`. It has completely changed my way of thinking in a lot of points in my current project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I thought that using `.Any()` would work, but I actually haven't been able to get that to function as expected.

You should be able to make it work by applying `Any()` to `terms`, like this:

```
var result = list
         .Where(n => terms.Any(t => n.Foo.Contains(t)))
         .ToList();
```

Comment: Everything in this thread has been helpful, but this one has solved it completely. I was just using `Any` wrong. I will post the entire, completed code in a moment.

Comment: This solves the actual question asked about how to aggregate them together, at least. I'm still not able to get this to work with what I wanted it to, but I'm closer.

Comment: Man, this is really starting to baffle me. It works in your example, and the one I posted up top - but when I try to apply this to my real code it doesn't. But the types are the same. It's just `List<string>` everywhere.

Comment: There we go, the problem was not your answer, but my interpretation. Honestly this is why I hate the whole `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` thing so prevalent in programming guides. I hesitated to use it myself but it is kind of a defacto, but it confuses the hell out of me.

Comment: Hey man, @dasblinkenlight, I just want to thank you again for clarifying this. I am finding it useful in all kinds of places. I've pruned over 2000 lines of code just by converting it to simpler syntax using your input here.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
var result = list.Where(terms.Contains(n.Foo))
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to find out if [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element in one collection exists within another collection, so [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should work nicely here.

You can modify your second code snippet accordingly:

```
var sources = new List<string> { "baseline", "items" };

Baseline =
    Math.Round(Mutations.Where(n => n.Format.Is("Numeric"))
        .Where(n => sources.Intersect(n.Sources).Any())
        .Sum(n => n.Measurement), 3);
```

Regarding the part of the docs you quoted for "Intersect":

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

Every object can be compared to an object of the same type, to determine whether they're equal. If it's a custom class you created, you can implement [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then you get to decide what makes two instances of your class "equal".

In this case, however, we're just comparing strings, nothing special. "Foo" = "Foo", but "Foo" ≠ "Bar"

So in the above code snippet, we intersect the two collections by comparing all the strings in the first collection to all the strings in the second collection. Whichever strings are "equal" in both collections end up in a resulting third collection.

Then we call "Any()" to determine if there are any elements in that third collection, which tells us there was at least one match between the two original collections.

Comment: This one is the closest to what I really __want__, but the problem is that it just won't accept it. Let me get the error it is giving me for you ....

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'Contains(System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>)', candidates are:`

Comment: `bool Contains(string) (in class List<string>)`

`bool Contains<TSource>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource) in class Enumerable)`

Comment: Here we go, this is a screenshot of the actual error; http://i.imgur.com/K4o51Zc.jpg

Comment: And yes, `Sources` is just a `List<string>`, nothing special about it.

Comment: Wow, hey, this works too - I wish I could give you both answer credit. LINQ is so incredible, there is so much of it I don't know still, even though I've read multiple, multiple books on the subject.

Comment: I know that you're not getting as many points out of this as the accepted answer, but this also works - I beg of you, can you help me understand __why__ this works? I'm extremely confused about what `Intersect` is actually doing here. I also do not really understand how `Any()` is being applied as an after method without giving it a predicate.

Comment: The documentation for `Intersect` is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx and it reads ... `Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.`, now to be very honest, it might as well just say _`"Does magic"`_ because that "documentation" is extremely ... well, I have no idea what it is saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55773/discussion-between-ciel-and-grant-winney).

Comment: Thank you again for everything. This was immensely useful.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to let you know again that this was super helpful for other parts of my program. `Intersect` and `IEqualityComparer<T>` are some of the most useful parts of C# I didn't realize existed.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue when using `Any()` you can use a regular expression instead. Obviously, you should probably measure to make sure that regular expressions performs faster:

```
var terms = new List<string> { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "rho" };
var regex = new Regex(string.Join("|", terms));
var result = list
             .Where(n => regex.Match(n.Foo).Success);
```

This assumes that joining the terms to a list creates a valid regular expression but with simple words that should not be a problem.

One advantage of using a regular expression is that you can require that the terms are surrounded by word boundaries. Also, the predicate in the `Where` clause may be easier to understand when compared to a solution using `Contains` inside `Any`.

Comment: This does accomplish the goal for my given example, but I feel it will be too hard for me to use routinely as things get more complex. I strongly appreciate the knowledge, and will keep this referenced for future use.

Comment: Hey, I tried this some more and it is actually really, really awesome. I will actually use this more than I immediately anticipated, but for other things. Thank you so much.

Comment: this is really awesome too. I absolutely love the way you made even a complex regex look so trivial. It's an entirely different take on what I asked and is a great way to bridge between some languages, as I can use this in places where C# compilation isn't an option, but I have the chance to use C# to 'prepare' a regex for another engine (such as when I am using `JINT`).

Answer (score 1):

I assume n.Foo is a string rather than a collection, in which case:

```
var terms = new List<string> { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "rho" };

var list = (new List<string> { "alphabet", "rhododendron" })
    .Select(x => new { Foo = x });

var result = list.Where(x => terms.Any(y => x.Foo.Contains(y)));
```

Comment: I have to be missing something, because this is similar to what @Grant Winney posted and neither are working. `n.Foo` is a `List<string>`.

Comment: Hey @stovroz, this was indeed good. It did not solve my problem, but I found it an interesting way to go about it. I will certainly find this useful in other places, as I had not considered using `Select` to get any of the information.